# Configure an existing theme on Shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm totally new with Shopify, im trying to Configure an existing theme and fallow the full process form the guideline here (https://shopify.github.io/themekit/) but when I try to run the command theme download it shows me the error 
requested theme was not found
though I setup Private apps and configure everything
so is there anything that I missed out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all try to grab Correct ID of your Store from here:  https://www.screencast.com/t/ZySPCKUTi 
   https://www.screencast.com/t/If0MHah3
2. And run CMD Command from your destination folder path.

Answer (score 1):

This error is showing when you use the wrong theme ID, check it.